# Reading input from a file in c++

Tags: arrays, c++11

How can i read input from this (below given link) file(.txt) and store it in a 2-d array or a 2d vector ?

input file link :

http://spark-public.s3.amazonaws.com/algo1/programming_prob/kargerMinCut.txt

P.S. - i don't want to store them as a string .

Comment: Break this problem down and research it better. First start with how to read a file in C++. Then, storing the read contents into an array. Once you have a specific question, people can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public int[][] readFileToArray(String nameoffile){

    int[][] outArray = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {

        reader =   new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\U383250\\Desktop\\test.txt"));
        String line = null;
        String[] lineVariables = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null ) {
            lineVariables = line.split("\n"); 
            if(lineVariables!=null && lineVariables.length>0){
                outArray = new int[lineVariables.length][100]; // put you line length here instead of 100 
                int i = 0;
                for(String string : lineVariables){
                    String[] eachLine = string.split("\\s+");
                    int j = 0;
                    for(String inLine : eachLine){
                        outArray[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(inLine);
                        j++;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
    finally{
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return outArray;
}
```

You should specify the size of your 2d array by your own logic/requirement

Comment: Can you please provide the code in c++ or c ?

Comment: actually i m a beginner in c and dont know anything about java , so i am not able to check whether this is the one i need it or not  . so , if you know c ,can u please provide the code

Answer (score -3):

to define a 2D array we write

```
int x[5]//(rows)[5]//(coloums)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.